# iOS8 issue when trying to push multiple UIViewControllers in NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, xcode6

I have 6 UIViewControllers connected with push segues with identifiers and a functionality in my app to 'jump' to the desired `UIViewController` using this method for stacking ViewControllers:

```
- (void) JumpTo6 {
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
UIViewController *a =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2"];
[nav pushViewController:a animated:NO];
UIViewController *b =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"3"];
[nav pushViewController:b animated:NO];
UIViewController *c =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"4"];
[nav pushViewController:c animated:NO];
UIViewController *d =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"5"];
[nav pushViewController:d animated:NO];
UIViewController *e =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"6"];
[nav pushViewController:e animated:YES];
```

When using iOS7 everything worked fine. I would fire this method, and let's say I was on `UIViewController` one, the system would stack every `UIViewController` up to UI VC 6 and `UIViewController` six would get presented with the animation.

But on iOS8 strange behaviour appears. The system shows me the `UIViewcontroller` 5 for a brief period of time, and then goes to `UIViewcontroller` 6. This is something I don't want.

To sum things up:

iOS 7: 1 -----> 6 - desirable

iOS 8: 1 -----> 5 (for a brief period of time) ----> 6 - undesirable

My question is how to achieve desirable effect using iOS 8. Ty!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is not the normal way to use a navigation controller. If the user hits the back button (From 6) in this scenario, he will go back to 5, which he has never seen before -- he would be expecting to go to 1 since that's where he came from.

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Comment: Well, hopefully, Apple will be OK with that. I don't know whether that violates the HIG or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method:

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
              animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to set all the controllers at a time showing only the last.

In your case:

```
- (void) JumpTo6 {
  UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
  UIViewController *a = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2"];
  UIViewController *b = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"3"];
  UIViewController *c = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"4"];
  UIViewController *d = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"5"];
  UIViewController *e = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"6"];
  NSArray *viewControllers = nav.viewControllers;
  NSArray *newViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:a, b, c, d, e, nil];
  [nav setViewControllers:[viewControllers arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newViewControllers] animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That would be great, but the `(void)setViewControllers` method will replace view controllers managed by the navigation controller with the specified items which is something I can't go with. It is essential that the view controllers are managed by the navigation controller.

Comment: @AndrejTrilavov `setViewControllers:animated:` will replace the view controllers *that are managed by the navigation controller*. The navigation controller will then manage the newly set view controllers. This answer is the correct solution to your problem and will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite Yes, you are right. I was to quick to conclude otherwise. But when I try to implement this method, I get `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:animated:'` (last line of code). Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, again. Ty! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite & Heinz Yes, tested. Works like a charm. You have helped me tremendously. Love!