# iOS8: Pushing View Controller in prepareForSegue for another flashes it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I have 3 View Controllers, conveniently named A, B, C.
A is presented using a UINavigationController, and has a push segue to C.

My desired effect is that after performing the segue, C's back button will pop us into **B**, and then B's back button pop us to A. Effectively, this means that segueing to C will put both B and C onto the stack.

in iOS7, I've used the following (redacted) code successfully:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        CViewController *slotViewer = segue.destinationViewController;
        /* Do Stuff */

        BViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];   
}
```

The result appearance was a smooth transition from A to C, while B is loaded and B's ViewWillAppear is only called when clicking on C's back button.

However, on iOS8, this breaks: The transition briefly flashes B on the screen, its viewWillAppear is called, and only then C is shown.

Any idiomatic way to perform this transition in iOS8?

I know I can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169483/ios8-issue-when-trying-to-push-multiple-uiviewcontrollers-in-navigationcontrolle) but it feels awkward, and I'd rather use the Segues all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method (setViewControllers) you linked was designed to do exactly you want. Why is it awkward? It's provided by Apple.. Besides that there is no way to use segues only. Your previous solution was same like pushing first one programatically and right after second one by interface builder..this is awkward man:).

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. You're not supposed modify the navigation stack like that! It's awkward.